# Populating view menu dynamically using commands

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am creating the commands(STYLE_CHECK) dynamically(At runtime) using the below code and adding these to view menu.

```java
final IMenuService menuService = (IMenuService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IMenuService.class);
AbstractContributionFactory viewMenuAddition = new AbstractContributionFactory("menu:show?after=additions",
        null) {
    @Override
    public void createContributionItems(IServiceLocator serviceLocator, IContributionRoot additions) {
    List<String> hardLabels = ReadVzFile.getHwLabels();
    LinkedHashSet<String> sections = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    //List will be poulated here
    for (Iterator<String> iterator = sections.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        String hardLabel = iterator.next();

        ICommandService commandService = (ICommandService) serviceLocator.getService(ICommandService.class);
        Command command = commandService.getCommand(hardLabel);
        RegistryToggleState registryToggleState = new RegistryToggleState();
        registryToggleState.setInitializationData(null, null, "true");
        registryToggleState.setShouldPersist(false);
        System.out.println(registryToggleState.getValue());
        command.addState("org.eclipse.ui.commands.toggleState", registryToggleState);
        command.define(hardLabel, hardLabel + "command created dynamically", commandService
            .getCategory("org.eclipse.ui.category.window"));
        IHandlerService handlerService = (IHandlerService) serviceLocator.getService(IHandlerService.class);
        handlerService.activateHandler(command.getId(), new AbstractHandler() {

        @Override
        public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
            System.out.println("Command executed !" + event.getCommand().getId());
            System.out.println(event.getCommand().getState("org.eclipse.ui.commands.toggleState")
                .getValue());
            return null;
        }

        });

        // build a couple of command-based contribution parameters
        CommandContributionItemParameter pAA = new CommandContributionItemParameter(serviceLocator,
            hardLabel + " command menu", hardLabel, CommandContributionItem.STYLE_CHECK);
        pAA.label = hardLabel;
        CommandContributionItem itemAA = new CommandContributionItem(pAA);
        itemAA.setVisible(true);
        additions.addContributionItem(itemAA, null);
    }
    }
};
menuService.addContributionFactory(viewMenuAddition);
```

But When I see in the view menu all menu items ARE NOT CHECKED(Selected).
What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Tru using HandlerUtil, like that

```
HandlerUtil.toggleCommandState(command);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: No not working..after adding the statement "HandlerUtil.toggleCommandState(command);
" before the "additions.addContributionItem(itemAA, null);"

Comment: Have you tried to remove/comment out your own code, which modifies state? Also, you may want to put your code or the call to HandlerUtil.toggleCommandState into the "execute" method in AbstractHandler, since I assume it is actually time you want to change button state. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: No if I remove the code of adding state i.e    RegistryToggleState registryToggleState = new RegistryToggleState();
        registryToggleState.setInitializationData(null, null, "true");
        registryToggleState.setShouldPersist(false);
        System.out.println(registryToggleState.getValue());
        command.addState("org.eclipse.ui.commands.toggleState", registryToggleState);

Comment: am getting org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException: The command does not have a toggle state
 at org.eclipse.ui.handlers.HandlerUtil.toggleCommandState(HandlerUtil.java:653) exception from "HandlerUtil.toggleCommandState(command);"

Comment: I want all menu items should be selected by default so if I write code inside handlers execute method then this will be executed when menu items were clicked. Currently the menu items are shown like this [link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3pxBGD-v-ycMTJxZ1Z4dWpDdlU/edit) but I want these must be shown like this [link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3pxBGD-v-yca3ZGV1Y3enkyUXc/edit)

Comment: Check out this post in this case (it also contains link to an Eclipse documentation): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114764/toggling-the-state-of-a-menu-item . May be you need to refresh elements to force visual changes.